# Get the link for RSS item to display in feed

Tags: functions, rss

```
function wpbeginner_postrss($content) {
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
if(is_feed()) {
$coolcustom = get_field('fl_quote');
$link = the_permalink_rss(); 
$content = '<div>' .$coolcustom. '</div></br><div>This post first appeared on My site - read more at <a href="'. esc_url($link) .'">' . get_the_title_rss(). '&nbsp;&rarr;</a>';
}
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'wpbeginner_postrss');
add_filter('the_content', 'wpbeginner_postrss');
```

For some reason the  link is displayed empty inside the RSS feed. Is there something wrong with the way I obtain the $link ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `the_permalink_rss()` is `echo`ing it's content not `return`ing it.

If we look at the source of this function:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_permalink_rss/

We can just copy what it's doing, as it's a simple function.

`$link = esc_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink_rss', get_permalink() ) );`

Comment: I decided to just use: get_the_permalink() - is that a problem? because it works fine from what it seems

Comment: Nope, that will work also. It's just that if there are any plugins that are hooking into the the_permalink_rss filter to apply parameters to the URL they won't work anymore.